# Add items to generic List in base class

Tags: c#

I have the following existing class structure:

```
abstract class ClassA
{
    protected virtual ICollection<string> SomeCollection => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

abstract class ClassB : ClassA
{
    private readonly List<string> _emptySomeList = new List<string>();

    protected override ICollection<string> SomeCollection => _emptySomeList;
}

class ClassC : ClassB
{
    protected override ICollection<string> SomeCollection => new List<string> {
       "Item1",
       "Item2"
    };
}

class ClassD : ClassC
{
}
```

I want to add some additional items to ClassC.SomeCollection within ClassD. This should only happen once. I have tried doing this in the constructor and in a "!isInitialized" block, but in both cases calling SomeCollection.Add("Item3") has no effect. I.e. the new items are not added to the list. I have tried both "this" and "base."

Please shine a light on the obvious thing I'm missing here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please provide the code you've written i. e. where you call `Add()`? These are all instance properties/ fields so you have to call them on instances of objects, not the classes themselves. `ClassC.SomeCollection.Add()` therefore won't work. Also it does matter on which instance specifically you call the functions so without the calling code this answer cannot be answered.

Comment: Are you looking for `protected override ICollection<string> SomeCollection {get;} = new List<string> {"Item1","Item2"};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected override ICollection<string> SomeCollection => new List<string> {
   "Item1",
   "Item2"
};
```

is an [expression-bodied, read-only property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#read-only-properties) and returns a new list on each access. Adding an item will add an item to the returned list, but the next time the property is accessed, a new list is returned again.

This is syntactic sugar for and equivalent to the following property:

```
protected override ICollection<string> SomeCollection
{
   get
   {
       return new List<string> {
           "Item1",
           "Item2"
       };
   }
}
```

You need to return the same list on consecutive invocations, just like you did with your `ClassB`, e.g.

```
private readonly List<string> _list = new List<string>
{
   "Item1",
   "Item2"
};

protected override ICollection<string> SomeCollection => _list;
```

Answer (score 0):

`protected virtual ICollection<string> SomeCollection => throw new NotImplementedException();` declares a readonly (get-only) [auto-implemented property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties). As correctly explained by [@knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112968/knittl) the `override ICollection<string> SomeCollection => new List<string> ...` implementation will result in a new list created on every get. Though you don't need to explicitly declare a backing field for it - an alternative approach can be declaring readonly auto-property with initializer:

```
class ClassC : ClassB
{
    protected override ICollection<string> SomeCollection { get; } = new List<string>
    {
        "Item1",
        "Item2"
    };
}
```